React setState not rerendering
Started a course on ReactJS and on Chapter 4 I encountered this issue. I have verified with several posts and none work. setState() is any implementation has not re rendered the component.
const Content = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('defs');

  const handleNameChange = () =>{
    setName('Julian');
  }

  return (
    <main>
        <p >
           Hello {name}!
           {console.log(name)}
        </p>
        <button onClick={handleNameChange}>Change Name</button>  
    </main>
  )
}

I have also tried
const [name, setName] = useState({default: "Dave"});
  const handleNameChaneg = () => {
    setName({...name,default:"Julian"});

From console.log I can see that the state value is changing but for the life of me cannot get the component to re-render and display the changes.
ISSUE UPDATE: I used the same code on playcode.io and the web view updates changes. The changes do not update on local file. I am running web view in Firefox Dev edition.

It is working for me: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bold-moon-xplrrk

If the console.log in your code works, then it is re-rendering. It sounds weird if you see the console log but the DOM is not updated.

SOLVED!
I tired opening the port in different browsers and found that it was working as intended. I spent 3 hours trying to debug this issue.
The problem happens to be an Firefox addon called "Bionic Reader" which I regularly use for reading articles. It basically emboldens the first 2 syllables of each word to make reading easier. This happens to have conflicted with re-rendering of the site.
